# Small sample size - Mann Whitney, ANOVA or something else?

Tags: anova, small-sample

I am doing an MSc project determining the best DNA recovery method. I will be quantifying the DNA yield from three methods. Due to time and cost I will not be able to repeat the tests more than 10 times per method. In an ideal world this would be much higher.

I have to demonstrate whether there is any statistical significant difference between the results.

What would be the most appropriate test to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are comparing, the Mann-Whitney U is a test statistic of choice for small sample sizes. It's pretty much a more robust T test. You trade a tiny bit of precision for a big amount of usability (because really, when does using real world data actually meet the assumptions of a t-test?). And if you want to compare all the methods at once, in an ANOVA format, you can use a Kruskal–Wallis H test. The KW H statistic is pretty much a direct extension of the MW U statistic just like ANOVA is an extension of the T test.